# Jquery Autocompleter Submitting Empty Value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, symfony1

I am playing around with the Jquery Autocompleter in sfFormExtraPlugin but I am having trouble when i need to create a value not already in the autocomplete list.

The form always submits and empty value for the field with the autocomplete on it... i have found the mustMatch config option which is off by default .. i have also set it explicitly to off for the field in question.

Incidentally I have noticed if mustMatch is set to true the value in the field doesn't automatically clear.. it will remain with whatever was typed in...

Perhaps the problem lies with bugs in the JQueryAutocompleter? I am starting to suspect this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using JQueryAutocompleter in a symfony project but without sfFormExtraPlugin and it is working fine for values not in the autocomplete list. It is quite easy to work with it from [this example](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/), so I'd suggest tying to use JQueryAutocompleter without the plugin to see if things go better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your  help, The plugin actually adds a hidden field which it writes the ID to and the autocomplete field has the same id but ads an autocomplete prefix this is the one that is displayed and holds the the value of the key value pair where the key is the id. I was able to modify the plugin to use new values.